# Cutting random bytes off of file byte array in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, byte

So I've been working on this project for a while now, involving LSB steganography. Really fun stuff. Anyways, I just finished writing the code for embedding and extracting files from an image(instead of just plaintext), and I'm running into this problem. I can recognize the MIME and extension of the bytes, but because the embedded file doesn't usually take up all of the LSBs of the image, there's a lot of garbage data. So I have the extracted file + some garbage in the byte array right after it. I need to figure out how to cut these, so that the file that is being exported is the correct, smaller size.

TLDR: I have a byte array with a recognized file in it, with some additional random bytes. How do I find out where the file ends and the random bytes begin?

Remember this is all in C#.
Any advice is appreciated.

Link to my project for reference: https://github.com/nicosogangstar/Steg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you have two options.

### End of stream marker

This is the more direct approach of the two, but it may lack some versatily depending on what data you want to hide. After you embed your data, continue with embedding a unique sequence of bits/bytes such that you know it cannot be prematurely encountered in the data before. As you extract the bits, you can stop reading once you encounter this sequence. If you expect to hide only readable text, i.e. bytes with ascii codes between 32 and 127, your marker can be as short as eight 0s, or eight 1s. However, if you intend to hide any sort of binary data, where each byte has a chance of appearing, you may accidentally encounter the marker while extracting legitimate data and thus halt the process prematurely.

### Header information

You can add a header preceding data, e.g, another 16-24 bits (or any other amount) which can be translated to a number that tells you how many bits/bytes/pixels to read before stopping. For example, if you want to hide a byte array of size 1000, first embed 2 bytes related to the length of the secret and then follow it with the actual data. More specifically, split the length in 2 bytes, where the first byte has the 8th to 15th bits and the second byte has the 0th to 7th bits of the number 1000 in binary.

```
00000011 11101000    1000 in binary
       3      -24    byte values
```

You can embed all sorts of information in a header, such as whether the data is encrypted or compressed with some algorithm, the original filename of the date, how many LSBs to read for extracting the information, etc.

Comment: Both good solutions, thank you. I was hoping there was some way to detect file ends, but its fine. :/

Comment: It really depends on the data you're embedding. For example, if you're extracting the raw data of a bitmap image, its header has information of how many pixels/bytes to read until the end of the file. JPEG has markers of its own to mark the end of file. Other formats have nothing. If you want to recognise specific file formats, you have to implement a decoder (for each one and only when possible) to figure that out for you. It's much easier to tell yourself how many bytes you want to read.